# I can't solve this error [Error] cannot convert 'list**' to 'list*' for argument '1' to 'void remplire(list*)'

Tags: c

[Error] cannot convert 'list**' to 'list*' for argument '1' to 'void remplire(list*)'

Im trying to crate a program that fill a doubly chained list but im facing this error i mostly tried all what i know but the error still appears

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                        
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
struct cellule{
    cellule *suiv;
    cellule *prec;
    int val;
};

struct list{
    cellule *tete;
    cellule *fin;
};
```

Creation of the list

```
void creation(list *l)
{
    l->tete = NULL;
    l->fin = NULL;
}
```

Void for filling the list

```
void remplire(list *l)
{   
    int x;
    cellule *nvl;
    nvl = (struct cellule*)malloc(sizeof(struct cellule));
    nvl->prec = NULL;
    nvl->suiv = NULL;
    printf("saisie un valeur");
    scanf("%d\n",&x);
    nvl->val = x;
    if (l->tete == NULL)
    {
        l->tete = nvl;
        l->fin = nvl;
    }else
    {
        (l->fin)->suiv = nvl;
        nvl->prec = l->fin;
        l->fin = nvl;
    }
}
```

Void for Showing the list

```
void affiche(list *l)
{
    cellule *cmp;
    cmp = l->tete;
    do
    {
        printf("%d",cmp->val);
        cmp = cmp->suiv;
    }while(cmp != NULL);
}
```

Main program

```
int main()
{
    list *l;
    int n;
    //asking for the list size//
    `z`printf("saisie la taille de list\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //filling the list with a for loop//
    for (int i=0 ;i<n;i++)
    {

        remplire(&l);   
    }
//showing list//
affiche(&l);
}
```

Comment: Either give the function just `l` or change it to take a `list**`. Which one is the right one depends on what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to modify `l` in the function or not? In any case you don't give `l` any value anywhere so using it is undefined behavior.

Comment: i want to fill the list l i think that means modifying it two.

Comment: Then change the function to take a variable of type `list**` and go from there

Comment: Where is `creation()` called?

Comment: hey i found the problem in the main program i changed the declaration from 
list *l;
to :
list l;
then i changed the creation void  from :
l->tete = NULL
l->fin = NULL
to:
l.tete = NULL;
l.fin = NULL;